# Select dropdown not showing selected value php

Tags: php, dropdown, select, options

I'm using `Wordpress Settings API`. Everything works as it should except this `select` dropdown. When I select an option, the value echoed is correct but in the dropdown it displays the default first value i.e `6` and not the selected one. Where am I going wrong?

```
 public function someplugin_select() {
            $options = get_option( 'plugin_252calc');
            echo $options; //shows the correct value selected
            $items = array();
            for ($i=6; $i <=10; $i+= 0.1) 
            { 
                $items[] = $i;
            }

            echo '<select id="cf-nb" name="cf-nb">';
            foreach ( $items as $item )
            {
                echo '<option value="'. $item .'"';
                if ( $item == $options ) echo' selected="selected"';
                echo '>'. $item .'</option>';
            }

            echo '</select>';           

        }
```

Comment: its `selected="selected"` being echoed?

Comment: No. It's not echoing `selected=selected` even if the value equals options

Comment: do a `var_dump('$item == $options')` to check if its being true at least 1 time

Comment: it's returning false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your `$item == $option` condition is always failing is because of the way PHP compares floats!

Try the following instead:

```
echo "<option value='$item'" . selected (abs ($item - $options) <= 0.01, true, false) . ">$item</option>" ;
```

See [Comparing floats](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#language.types.float.comparison) for more info.

Comment: float comparison is so farked in php

Comment: for anyone who's interested: the problem is not PHP, per se, it's the binary representation of floats.  see [Comparing Floating Point Numbers, 2012 Edition](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) for a good discussion of why the _epsilon_ method above is not ideal in all cases (but certainly good enough for the OP).

Answer (score 0):

I went through this, and I could tell that there's a WP function called `selected`, which you can see in this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/selected/). Use this function instead of doing: `if ( $item == $options )`. And your code could look like this:

```
foreach ( $seconds as $second => $time ) {
   ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $second; ?>" <?php selected( $browser_cache_ttl, $second ); ?>><?php echo $time; ?></option>
   <?php
}
```

So that function loops through `$seconds` and get the `$second` and `$time`, put te `$second` as  value, then call the selected function which the first parameter is the value to compare and the second one is the current value, if those values are the same, it'll be selected.

I think that's what you're looking for. Tell me if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your select with this... Hope it works...

```
        echo '<select id="cf-nb" name="cf-nb">';
        foreach ( $items as $item ){
            $if_selected = $item == $options ? "selected='selected'" : "";
            echo "<option value='{$item}' {$if_selected}>$item</option>";

        }

        echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Not sure why, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any better answers, but I feel I have a similar-enough issue to add to this question instead of making a new one.

I started with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbJiwm5YL5Q&t=3969s and got as far as 1:05:00 and this is my current version is

```
function selectpageHTML() {?>
            <select name="lp_actPage"> 
                <?
                    $pages = get_pages();                       foreach ( $pages as $page ) {                               
                                $title = $page->post_title;
                                echo "<option value='$title'" . selected(get_option('lp_actPage', $title)) .">$title</option>";
                                } ?>
            </select>
        <?}
```

however, instead of comparing floats I was thinking I could compare string values instead, but so far no dice.

I also tried assigning a variable as the page ID and using that variable as the option value as well as the 2nd argument in the get_option() function, but still no joy.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/254622)