# HTML dropdown setting not showing last saved value in the database

Tags: php, dropdown, select

I want a select-dropdown field to display the last saved option in the database; I started with this video from YT, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbJiwm5YL5Q&t=3969s and got as far as 1:05:00 and this is my current version

```
function selectpageHTML() {?>
            <select name="lp_actPage"> 
                <?  $pages = get_pages();
                        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {                               
                                $slug = $page->post_name;
                                $title = $page->post_title;
                                echo "<option value='$slug'" . selected(get_option('lp_actPage', $slug)) .">$title</option>";
                        } ?>
            </select>
        <?}
```

I also looked at [Select dropdown not showing selected value php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257955/select-dropdown-not-showing-selected-value-php/408367#408367), but instead of comparing floats I'm looking to compare strings.

Comment: you should replace all instances of `<?` with `<?php`, short tags are deprecated and in newer versions of PHP don't work at all. You should also avoid directly embedding variables into quotes the way that code does with `$slug` as it's not possible to apply escaping and is a great way to inject malicious HTML. It should be `echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $slug ) . '" '.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```php
selected(get_option('lp_actPage', $slug))
```

`selected` needs 2 parameters, but you gave it 1, and `get_option` wants 1 parameter but you gave it 2.

If we reformat this, the problem becomes much clearer:

```php
selected(
    get_option('lp_actPage', $slug)
)
```

What's necessary is:

```php
selected(
    get_option('lp_actPage')
    $slug
)
```

#### Sidenote

`get_pages` doesn't use the normal post querying code, and doesn't benefit from the same enhancements and plugin integration you get from other functions.

Instead of `get_pages`, consider:

```php
$pages = get_posts( [
    'suppress_filters' => false, // enable caching
    'post_type' => 'page', // we want pages
    'post_status' => 'publish', // speed up by asking for only published posts
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
] );
```

Likewise, don't use `<?` use `<?php` or your code will break when your host upgrades PHP in the future.

Comment: Thanks, Tom, your solution is working, and I fixed my coding schema per your recommendation